# Open two windows onClick button javascript

Tags: javascript, forms

I am trying to open two different windows with the click of a button, but when i click the button it opens the same window twice. This is my function:

```
function flush(form) {
    var custid = form.custid.value;
    var url1 = "https://www.blabla.com?type=customer&id="+custid;
    flushWindow1 = window.open(url1);
    var url2 = "https://web.blabla.com?type=customer&id="+custid;
    flushWindow2 = window.open(url2);
}
```

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: Are you sure you are typing the URL correctly? it works on fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4kApx/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From : [JSfiddle Two windows on a Click](http://jsfiddle.net/zaheerahmed/u2DBx/)

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    $('input').click(function(){
        window.open("https://www.google.com.pk/search?q=123&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a")
        window.open("https://www.google.com.pk/search?q=abc&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a")
    });
});
```

Comment: This works in fiddle, but how to i write this in the same syntax as the question?

Comment: What do u mean by same window twice?? Means two windows with same url? if yes then do check your url bcoz:  var url1 = "https://www.blabla.com?type=customer&id="+custid; looks exactly same to  var url2 = "https://web.blabla.com?type=customer&id="+custid; may be this is the reason, same window open twice.

Answer (score 0):

Try providing second argument to window.open() method, which is the name of the window, if name is different then same url will open in different windows. e.g.

```
function flush(form) {
    var custid = form.custid.value;
    var url1 = "https://www.blabla.com?type=customer&id="+custid;
    flushWindow1 = window.open(url1,"flushWindow1");
    var url2 = "https://web.blabla.com?type=customer&id="+custid;
    flushWindow2 = window.open(url2,"flushWindow2");   
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/shSn8/)

Comment: It's not the same, the subdomain changes (www.blabla.com - web.blabla.com)

Comment: right, new window depends on the second argument and not on the url. Thats why you can also access the window, even without the refrence, using this second argument e.g. win = window.open(new_url,"flushWindow1") will give you the same window even though url is different but name is same.

Comment: This does the same, opens two of the same window.

Comment: As I understand he wants two windows, with different content, name the window is usefull to refer to the same window later, I don't see what changes in this case to add the second  argument: http://jsfiddle.net/4kApx/1

Comment: did you check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/shSn8/   even if this fiddle doesn't work for you, try provoding third argument i.e. window options e.g. "height=700,width=800" etc. I also faced the similar problem (due to browser settings may be) and did something like this -

Comment: window.open(url2,"flushWindow2","height=700,width=800");

Answer (score 0):

try open in new window/tab by add parameter `'_blank'` 
and then focus the window you want by place `window.focus();` behind window you want to focus after open two new window

```
function flush(form) {
    var custid = form.custid.value;
    var url1 = "https://www.blabla.com?type=customer&id="+custid;
    flushWindow1 = window.open(url1, '_blank');
    var url2 = "https://web.blabla.com?type=customer&id="+custid;
    flushWindow2 = window.open(url2, '_blank');
    window.focus(); // focus on url2
}
```

Comment: This also open two of the same window.