# 2 pdf's open with one click on website

Tags: javascript, html, pdf

looking for one link to open 2 or more pdfs.  In my example, I used urls, hoping they both behave the same.  I have clients that click the "required" link, so I need each requirement to open in a new window. I do not want new tabs, as the agent might not realize that there are still more requirements.  I prefer the pdf's to open in a reader, so they can just fill it out and send back.  I cant use pdfs on jsfiddle, that I know of, but the answers I did get will give me a great start.  Thanks - I just realized our company has popups blocked, which is why only one link opens.  No one has admin rights to override that, so looking for a work around.
my jsfiddle:[my attempts](http://jsfiddle.net/jim54729/s5075sp1/1/)

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=onclick+new+window','newerwindow','width=200');return false;window.open('http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132122/open-url-in-new-window-with-javascript','125','width=600');return false;">windowOpen twice</a>
```

and another attempt:

```
<a href="http://www.w3schools.com" href="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_href.asp">2 hrefs?</a>
```

and another attempt:

```
<a href="http://www.microsoft.com" target="_blank" onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com'); window.open('http://www.yahoo.com','mywindowName');">href+2onClicks</a>
```

some of these codes come from this site, but do not work for me.  I need it to work IE, (intranet)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open two windows onClick button javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12779771/open-two-windows-onclick-button-javascript)

Comment: The issue lies with not naming your windows that you are trying to open.

Comment: Maybe its just my browser then, I did try the link provided by scrappedcola, and it only opened the google with the 123, I did not get the second google with the abc.

Comment: This does work to open 2 tabs, but since they are pdf's I would rather have them open as a new window or better yet an adobe reader.  Thanks for the link, any ideas on a way without 2 tabs?

Comment: tabs vs windows is a users personal settings preference and you generally don't have too much control over that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try  whit a function

```
 <a href="#" onclick="openMultiple();">2 hrefs?</a>

<script> 
  function openMultiple(){
     window.open('http://www.google.com');   
     window.open('http://www.yahoo.com','mywindowName');
  }
</script>
```